# JS doesn't work, syntax error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, analytics, prop

why this JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('a[href$=".pdf"]').prop('onClick', '_gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Pdf", "Download", "Download_pdf"]);');
    });
</script>
```

doesn't work? is there any quotes errors?

The script should find all the a tags with href ending in .pdf and adds to it the onClick attribute with the value that follows (Google Analytics Event), but in Chrome Developer Tool Console appears this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <(…)
```

is there any syntax error?

Comment: Is this the full code?

Comment: Don't add inline onclick events to elements. Add a `.click()` handler instead. Does the error happen at page load or when you click on the link?

Comment: Try removing `"."` at `".pdf"`

Comment: Don't encourage this type of question. Inform the asker to [ask a better question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Yes this is the full script. I try removing "." at ".pdf" but there is the same error. I try it in the Chrome Developer Tool Console in a page where there is a a tag the links to a pdf file.

Comment: > '_gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Pdf", "Download", "Download_pdf"]);'
This should have been a function definitioin

Comment: Do you have this _in a .js file_? You don't need the `<script>` tag unless it is directly in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the error you get when you paste a `<script>` tag into an external `.js` file, because it barfs trying to parse the first `<`.

Paste this directly into your HTML, or remove the `<script>` tag.

Comment: Thank you, it works now!